# shell scripting to send mail

Tags: shell, scripting

Created script and its writing in sample.txt, Unable to grep the below text "EX_R02"and need to send mail.

```
cat sample.txt|mailx -a sample.txt -s "GG status Report" $MAIL_LIST
```

`Sample.txt`:

```
Program     Status      Group       Lag at Chkpt  Time Since Chkpt

MANAGER     RUNNING
EXTRACT     STOPPED     EX_R02      00:00:03      01:10:37
```

Comment: As far as I can see, there _is_ no text under `EX_R02`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you by "grep the below text `EX_R02`" mean "grep the text below for `EX_R02`", then you may simply replace your `cat` with `grep "EX_R02"`:

```
grep "EX_R02" sample.txt | mailx -a sample.txt -s 'GG status Report' "$MAIL_LIST"
```